# RBF interpolation: LinAlgError: singular matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

The following call:

```
rbf = Rbf(points[0], points[1], values,epsilon=2)
```

results in an error:

```
LinAlgError: singular matrix
```

with the following values:

```
In [3]: points
Out[3]: 
(array([71, 50, 48, 84, 71, 74, 89, 76, 70, 77, 74, 79, 83, 71, 72, 78, 73,
       84, 75, 65, 73, 82, 48, 86, 74, 86, 66, 74, 68, 74, 81, 74, 88, 66,
       57, 50, 72, 86, 72, 92, 81, 67, 82, 78, 69, 70, 73, 71, 76, 72, 74,
       75]),
 array([32, 34,  4, 35,  1,  7, 47, 16, 37, 14, 65, 18, 32,  4,  3, 27, 25,
       34, 18, 25,  6, 25, 34, 41, 16, 35, 44,  2, 32,  2, 37, 60, 45, 32,
       33, 42, 54, 31, 18, 38, 24, 18, 45, 48,  9, 63, 56, 45,  9, 59,  5,
       12]))

In [4]: values
Out[4]: 
array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
        1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
        1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
        1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
```

What can I do to avoid it and still solve the interpolation problem?

Comment: If all the values are 1, then you already know the interpolated value at any point should also be 1. And if the values are not all 1, then you (probably?) will not encounter the singular matrix error.

Comment: @unutbu - I thought rbf would use an RBF around each value. Shouldn't the values decrease as I move away from each 1 for each RBF? (i.e. I would get a sum of gaussians for each location)

Comment: The **sum** of the radial basis functions has to equal 1 at each of the locations specified by `points`. The individual RBFs will not equal 1 at those points. Only the sum must equal 1. The problem is there is no sum of RBFs which can equal 1 at all those points.

Comment: Also, the [default basis function is `multiquadric`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.Rbf.html), not `gaussian`.

Comment: Above, where I said "sum of the radial basis functions", I should have said "sum of the *weighted* radial basis functions".

Comment: Thanks @unutbu - I guess that what I am looking for is different then. Perhaps what I am looking for is a convolution of my points with an  RBF (e.g. a gaussian). Any thoughts on how to accomplish this with numpy/scipy? The X,Y,Z values that I have (the ones I included in the OP) are meant to represent locations where an event happened, and I want to compute the probability on a 2D field of that event happening (the probability should fade as I move away from those observations). If you have any thoughts, let me know, and I will update the post accordingly.

Comment: you have "event=1" always, probability is 100%, otherwise could have tried [Probabilistic predictions with GPC](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/gaussian_process.html#probabilistic-predictions-with-gpc) with [sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.RBF](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.RBF.html#sklearn-gaussian-process-kernels-rbf), just take into consideration [Pro/Contra of GP](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/gaussian_process.html#gaussian-processes) or P.S. [other kernels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(statistics))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is [kernel density estimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation). You can use [`scipy.stats.gaussian_kde`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html) for this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
from matplotlib import pyplot as pp

# kernel density estimate of the PDF
kde = gaussian_kde(points)

# evaluate the estimated PDF on a grid
x,y = np.mgrid[40:101,-20:101]
z = kde((x.ravel(),y.ravel())).reshape(*x.shape)

# plot
fig,ax = pp.subplots(1,1)
ax.hold(True)
pc = ax.pcolor(x,y,z)
cb = pp.colorbar(pc)
cb.ax.set_ylabel('Probability density')
ax.plot(points[0],points[1],'o',mfc='w',mec='k')

pp.show()
```

[image]

The [`statsmodels`](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/index.html) module also has [some more elaborate tools](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/kernel_density.html?highlight=kde) for kernel density estimation.

Comment: be carefull with [bandwidth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) param of `scipy.stats.gaussian_kde`

Comment: [Kernel density estimation & other algos](https://sites.stat.washington.edu/mmp/courses/527/spring23/handouts/l4good-clustering-np.pdf) , implementation in [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html) - usecases recommmendations

Answer (score 3):

I got same error. 
Finally I found why I get the error.

you have 2 point with same coordinate. (74,2)
check the values have same coordinate in 28th, 30th.

In my thinking, even if you have same value on same point it emit singular matrix error.