# Inaccurate interpolation with scipy.interpolate.Rbf()

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

When I execute the following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import Rbf

x_coarse, y_coarse = np.mgrid[0:5, 0:5]
x_fine, y_fine = np.mgrid[1:4:0.23,1:4:0.23]
data_coarse = np.ones([5,5])

rbfi = Rbf(x_coarse.ravel(), y_coarse.ravel(), data_coarse.ravel())

interpolated_data = rbfi(x_fine.ravel(), y_fine.ravel()).reshape([x_fine.shape[0], 
                                                                  y_fine.shape[0]])

plt.imshow(interpolated_data)
```

the array `interpolated_data` has values ranging from 0.988 to 1.002 and the corresponding plot looks like this:

[image: Plot of the array 'data_fine']

However, I would expect that in such a simple interpolation case, the interpolated values would be a lot closer to the correct value, i.e. 1.000.

I think the variations in the interpolated values are caused by the different distances from the interpolated points to the given data points.

My question is: Is there a way to avoid this behavior? How can I get an interpolation that is not weighted by the distance of the interpolated points to the data points and gives me nothing but 1.000 in `interpolated_data`?

Comment: have a look on the first graph on this answer (similar example but in 1d): https://stackoverflow.com/a/51653039/8069403 . It looks like the same overshoot just before the last point. (The basis function is not the same.) Did you try [`griddata`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I would expect that in such a simple interpolation case,

An unwarranted expectation. The RBF interpolation, as its name says, uses radial basis functions. By default the basis function `sqrt((r/epsilon)**2 + 1)` where r is the distance from a data point and epsilon is a positive parameter. There is no way for a weighted sum of such functions to be identically constant. RBF interpolation isn't like a linear or bilinear interpolation. It's a rough interpolation suitable for rough data.

By setting an absurdly large epsilon, you can get closer to 1; just because it makes the basis functions nearly identical on the grid.

```
rbfi = Rbf(x_coarse.ravel(), y_coarse.ravel(), data_coarse.ravel(), epsilon=10)
# ... 
print(interpolated_data.min(), interpolated_data.max())
# outputs 0.9999983458255883 1.0000002402521204
```

However this is not a good idea, because when the data is **not** constant, there will be too much long-range influence in the interpolant.

> gives me nothing but 1.000 in interpolated_data?

That would be linear interpolation. [`LinearNDInterpolator`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator.html#scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator) has similar syntax to `Rbf`, in that it returns a callable.

```
linear = LinearNDInterpolator(np.stack((x_coarse.ravel(), y_coarse.ravel()), axis=-1), 
                              data_coarse.ravel())
interpolated_data = linear(x_fine.ravel(), y_fine.ravel()).reshape([x_fine.shape[0], y_fine.shape[0]])
print(interpolated_data.min(), interpolated_data.max())
# outputs 1.0 1.0
```

There is also a [`griddata`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html#scipy.interpolate.griddata) which has more interpolation modes.