# What are the best libraries and approaches to interpolate between uniformly distributed sensors over a floor plan?

Tags: python, scipy, heatmap, temperature, linear-interpolation

My goal is to build a temperature gradient map over a floor plan to display minute changes in temp. via uniformly distributed sensors.

As far as I understand most heatmap tools available work with point density to produce heatmaps whereas what I'm looking for is a gradient based on varying values of individual points (sensors) on the map. I.e. something like [this](https://miro.medium.com/max/600/0*ck7rdAOs6w9h5Pry.)...

which I nicked from [here](https://blog.ndustrial.io/temperature-gradient-maps-with-mapbox-gl-9f97fb44d5f2).

From what I've gathered interpolation will definitely be involved and it may just be Radial Basis Function Interpolation because it wouldn't require a grid as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51647590/2d-probability-distribution-with-rbf-and-scipy/51653039) post.

I've used the Anaconda distribution thus far. The data from sensors will be extracted from timescaleDB and the positions of sensors will be lat/long.

I've done very minor experimentation with the code from the link above and got this result. [Radial Basis Function Interpolation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fa2eG.png)

So here are my questions. Multiple python libraries have interpolation as a built-in function but which one of the libraries would be the best for the task described above? What parts of documentation should I read up on from libraries which can help me with this specific problem? Any good resource recommendations for this topic? Would anything else be required for this apart from interpolation?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. This is a side project I'd like to work on as a student, not commercial in any way shape or form.

Answer (score 0):

I like `scipy.interpolate` [library](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html). It has a lot of nice functions, the simplest that would work for you would probably be the `scipy.interpolate.interp2d()`, and if you want to go with an non linear distribution of sensors `griddata()` is very useful.